# jQuery: Is it possible to create tabs from a regular list?

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery and JS and trying to figure out if it is possible to create simple tabs from a basic unordered list. I have the below dynamically generated HTML (I cannot change the list markup, but I can insert the button markup).

All the tabs tutorials I have read only discuss using unordered lists for buttons and divs for the tabs themselves. Is is possible to do it the opposite way using parent `li`s for the tabs and `div`s for the buttons?

```
<div>tab 1</div>
<div>tab 2</div>
<div>tab 3</div>

<ul id="lists">
  <li>
    <h2>Title 1</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>An item</li>
      <li>An item</li>
      <li>An item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Title 2</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>An item</li>
      <li>An item</li>
      <li>An item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <h2>Title 3</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>An item</li>
      <li>An item</li>
      <li>An item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Comment: Yes it's possible. Most tab libraries allow you to specify the selector that you want to use.  If you add the name the specific tab library/plugin in your question, you could likely get a more detailed response.

Comment: You want to google "[lists for navigation](https://www.google.com/search?q=list+for+navigation)".

Comment: Short answer, yes. http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: @Mike I am just using jquery

Comment: @four there is nothing in those tutorials that deal with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="tab">tab 1</div>
<div class="tab">tab 2</div>
<div class="tab">tab 3</div>

<ul id="lists">
<li>
  <ul>
    <li><h2>Title 1</h2></li>
    <li>An item</li>
    <li>An item</li>
    <li>An item</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <ul>
    <li><h2>Title 2</h2></li>
    <li>An item</li>
    <li>An item</li>
    <li>An item</li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li>
  <ul>
    <li><h2>Title 3</h2></li>
    <li>An item</li>
    <li>An item</li>
    <li>An item</li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.tab {
  display: inline-block;
}

#lists {
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
}

#lists > li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: none;
  padding: none;
  display: none;
}
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
var tabs = $('#lists>li');

$('.tab').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var current_tab = tabs.eq($(this).index()).show();
  tabs.not(current_tab).hide();
});
```

Comment: Or do you mean drop downs instead of tabs? This question is a little vague.

Comment: oops, I messed up my HTML, have corrected it... I need tabs i.e. I need there to be three buttons at the top, the first parent list needs to appear, the other two need to be hidden. When button 2 is clicked list 1 needs to slide out of view and list 2 needs to replace it. Same for list 3 when button 3 is clicked.

Comment: The dropdowns aren't an hover event, but a click event?

Comment: yes it needs to work almost exactly like this: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ except its fine for the buttons to float separately above the tabs

Comment: I finally understand, and I've updated the answer to provide that functionality. I think the div approach can be cleaner but I understand that unfavorable boundaries can exist.